# Passing class in universal intent

Tags: java, android

So, right now in my App I'm sending data from actual class, to other, special class prepared to show informations from it, like here:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(ActualFluidsBernoullisEquationMenuActivity.this, DetailSubjectActivity.class);
```

Of course I'm also passing some info, on which I first need to create database reference, so there is like 15 lines of code.I have like 15 of those activities, which is creating a lot of boilerplate (the only changing line is which .this class I'm passing)
So I wanted to create universal method for intent like this:

```
 Intent engineeringTheoryIntent(String callingActivity, String subjectKey) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Class.forName(callingActivity).getClass().this,  DetailSubjectActivity.class);
}
```

(This doesn't work, just in case)

I just cannoot find the way how to properly pass first class. I tried Class.forName, I tried passing whole class, but not any of those works for me. I also didn't find any info if this is even possible (I'm kind of beginner in matter of android). So is there way to do it?

Comment: why not just pass Activity as the first argument instead of the string?

Comment: If I try to pass Activity, new Intent method still want to get Class name (and activity.getPackageName.this still doesn't work). So i tried to send it as String in something like ActualFluidsBernoullisEquationMenuActivity.class.getSimpleName()

Comment: `activity.getPackageName.this` is incorrect just use `activity.this`

Comment: `Intent engineeringTheoryIntent(Activity callingActivity, String subjectKey) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Intent intent = new Intent(callingActivity.this,  DetailSubjectActivity.class);`


I try it like this, and callingActivity.this is still marked as a error, with "Class name expected here"

Comment: just write `activity` there it'll work

Comment: Ah, so simple, and so effective ! That works ! Thank you very much :)

Comment: Do you want to transfer the control to another activity or you try to send a class or an instance as a parameter? If you want to transfer the control to another activity, be sure it was added to the manifest too. If you want to send an instance as parameter, the second parameter should be a class implementing Serializable or Parcelable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm posting the solution in the comments as an answer, so that it helps people who encounter similar problems in future.

So, instead of passing the activity class name (as `String`) you can simply pass the `Activity` itself as the argument to your universal function, like this :

```
Intent engineeringTheoryIntent(Activity callingActivity, String subjectKey) throws ClassNotFoundException {
```

and then you can create your `Intent` using it like this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(callingActivity,  DetailSubjectActivity.class);
```

So, your function will look something like this:

```
Intent engineeringTheoryIntent(Activity callingActivity, String subjectKey) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    Intent intent = new Intent(callingActivity,  DetailSubjectActivity.class);
}
```